# angular.js getting var from inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting data from the server with a service which is being called in this function:

```
LeadsSrv.async().then(function (d) {
    results = d.data;
});
```

I want to access the results outside of this function and then assign it to the scope, like this:

```
$scope.All_Leads = results;
```

Here is the server function:

```
LeadApp.service('LeadsSrv', function ($http) {
  var all = {
    async: function() {
        var promise = $http({
            url: '../app/Data.php',
            method: "POST",
            params: { req_id: 'leads_list', user_id: 1 }
        }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return all;
});
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the server function being called in an Angular service or is it within a controller?

Comment: i just updated my question with the server function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare the variable at the beginning of your script, then whenever the function fetching the data returns, it will update the value of that variable.

```
$scope.results = [];

LeadsSrv.async().then(function (d) {
    $scope.results = d.data;
});
```

Thanks to how angular works, you won't need to do anything else, it will also update the UI elements and bindings as well.

**Update:**

I'd do it this way:

Service:

```
LeadApp.service('LeadsSrv', function ($http) {
    var service = {
        postData: postData
    };

    return service;

    function postData(data) {
        return $http.post('../app/Data.php', data);      
    }
```

In the Controller:

```
//Initialize the variable
$scope.results = [];

var data = {
    req_id: 'leads_list',
    user_id: 1
};

LeadsSrv.postData(data).then(function (response) {
    //Once the $http.post succeeds, it will update your variable
    $scope.results = response.data;
});
```

This should do exactly what you're looking for, unless I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: yes your solutions works but am getting the data from the server which worked before also, but my question is how can i now access the scope var outside of the function to make it available on my entire site?

Comment: @jhondano could you please specify "entire site"? Is it all in angular, or is it a mix, etc?

Comment: The site is all in angular!

Comment: If you only use one controller, it should be available by `$scope.results` inside angular, or `{{results}}` in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going about this in following fasion.

Make your controller/directive ( whoever owns the $scope ) dependent on `LeadSrv` object. If it is not an "angular" component already wrap it in a factory, then inject it in your controller.

Then you simply do

```
LeadsSrv.async().then(function (d) {
    $scope.All_Leads = d.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are doing the right thing, except of **one** mistake: Your call is getting executed asynchronously. So that basically means, `results` won't have the expected value the time you are referring it to `$scope.All_Leads`, since the declaration is happening synchronously.

To achieve what you want, you have to use promises. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638060/understanding-js-promises) and Angulars [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Answer (score 0):

To check if your server is reporting an error, add a `.catch` method.

```
LeadsSrv.async().then(function onFulfilled(r) {
    console.log("DATA: ", r.data);
    $scope.results = r.data;
}).catch( function onRejected(response) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", response.status);
});
```