# Text to Html list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a html which will auto get the information for a *.txt file

```
something1
something2
something3
```

and output into this html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <ul>
                #here to output#
            </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I prefer to use JavaScript.  Some help is appreciated.

Comment: you're missing a piece of info. Where is the txt file located? In a remote server (to be fetched) or locally besides the html?

Comment: the txt file is locally beside the html

Comment: JavaScript which run in the browser can't access local files. You will have to network request it first.

Comment: use Ajax `load()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to request the file using AJAX call. Then you need to iterate through each line of response and generate DOM element (`li` in this case) and input line inside of it. After that insert each `li` element into your `ul` list.

You can achieve it using `jQuery` as you are probably new to JavaScript it's probably the easiest way.

What you need to do is request the file first:

```
$.ajax('url/to/your/file', {
    success: fileRetrieved
});
```

Now after the file is retrieved `jQuery` will call `fileRetrieved` method, so we have to create it:

```
function fileRetrieved(contents) {
    var lines = contents.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 1) {
        createListElement(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Now for each line from the file function `fileRetrieved` will call `createListElement` function passing line of text to it. Now we just need to generate the list element and inject it into DOM.

```
function createListElement(text) {
    var into = $('ul');
    var el = $('<li></li>').html(text);
    el.appendTo(into);
}
```

Of course you don't want to retrieve `into` element each time `createListElement` is called so just store it somewhere outside the function, it's your call, I'm just giving you the general idea.

Here is an example of the script (without `AJAX` call of course as we can't simulate it):

```js
var into = $('#result');

function fileRetrieved(contents) {
  var lines = contents.split('\n');
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 1) {
    createListElement(lines[i]);
  }
}

function createListElement(text) {
  var el = $('<li></li>').html(text);
  el.appendTo(into);
}

var text = $('#text').html();
fileRetrieved(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This element simulates file contents-->
<pre id="text">
  fdsafdsafdsa
  fdsafd
  safdsaf
  dsafdsaf
  dsafdsafds
  afdsa
</pre>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the file first, and then append it to your chosen place in the document.

You can for example use jQuery's `get` (or any other function like the native `fetch`), and then inject it into the ul element:

```
$.get("*.txt").then(x => $("ul").html("<li>" + x.split('\n').join('</li><li>') + "</li>"))
```

**Let's break this solution by steps:**

First, we need to request the external file:

```
 $.get("*.txt")
```

Read about jQuery's get [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Basicly it will request the file you asked for using network request, and return a [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638060/understanding-js-promises).

In the Promise's `then`, we can do stuff with the request's result after it is resolved. In our case we want to first break it by lines:

```
x.split('\n')
```

split will return an array that will look like this: ["line 1, "line 2", "line 3"].
JS arrays have the `join` method, which concat them to string while putting the string you want between the items. So after we do this:

```
x.split('\n').join('</li><li>')
```

We only need to add the `<li>` element to the start and end of the string like this:

```
"<li>" + x.split('\n').join('</li><li>') + "</li>"
```

Finally we appent it to your chosen element using jQuery's `html`.

Comment: How will this create `<li>`s?

Comment: @connexo I updated my answer with a simple solution to this.

Comment: That's an elegant one-liner, and almost precisely how I would do it with my adequate programming experience. However, considering this is a beginner's question, I doubt OP will understand much of it. :)

Comment: Nitpick, but I would instead do: `x.split("\n").map(s => \`<li>${s}</li>\`).join()` -- I think this carries more clarity and is more declarative.

Comment: I added an explanation. Anyway your solution looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      <html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul id="renderTxt_list">
      </ul>
      <input type="button" id="lesen" value="Read Data" />
    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lesen").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "testTxt.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success : function (data) {
                    $html = "";
                    var lines = data.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                        $html += '<li>'+lines[i]+'</li>';
                    }
                    $("body ul").append($html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think the part inside the `if (data != null)` conditional is perfectly enough here, no need to fire up an entire document.

Comment: is it proper now ?

Comment: It was "proper" earlier as well, it's just my taste to skip unnecessary code and focus on the subject. (the downvote is not from me)

Comment: i am not worried about downvote .. but i also realize, that line was useless. so consider you comment